# Find a function under some conditions

Tags: integration, analysis

I'm searching a function $ \varphi \in C^1([0, + \infty[) $ such that $ \varphi(0) = 0 $ and satisfying the following conditions:
$$ \frac{(\log t)^2}{\int_0^t (\varphi'(s))^2 (1+s) ds} \to 0,\ t \to + \infty, $$ and $$ \frac{(\varphi (t))^2}{\int_0^t (\varphi'(s))^2 (1+s) ds} - \log t\to 0,\ t \to + \infty. $$

At first glance, no evident contradiction. The behavior of the function suggests to try with functions of type $ (\log (1+t))^{\alpha} $ but it does not work. Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the proposal to close this question ? On which ground ?

Comment: Yes there is a contradiction: the second condition suggests $\varphi(t)\sim\ln t$, and the first condition doesn't sit well with that.

Comment: @JeanMarie: The problem is formulated in a way that strongly suggests it can be resolved by reasoned mathematical argument, and that is a good thing.  However the little *context* provided is consistent with having passed along an exercise without properly digesting the problem statement.  Details of how trying "with functions of type $(\log(1+t))^\alpha$ ... does not work" should be *shown* so that Readers are not unnecessarily repeating information already known to the poster.